# PHPStorm can't accept any input from keyboard after Find Occurrence

Tags: ubuntu, phpstorm

I'm using PHPStorm 7.0 in Ubuntu 13.10

I have problem after run command "Next Occurence" / "Prev Occurence" via keyboard shortcut "<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd>", I can not type any word or run any shortcut again in PHPStorm in any view (editor, Project, Favorite, etc), like PHPStorm ignored my keyboard input.
But fortunately it still can accepted mouse input, so I still can save my works, then I restarted it & back to normal.

In my Ubuntu I have modified 2 keyboard shortcuts,
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ALt</kbd> + <kbd>Down</kbd>  to  Disabled
<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>ALt</kbd> + <kbd>Up</kbd>  to  Disabled

Is this problem with PHPStorm or Ubuntu?

Comment: do you, by chance, have IBus daemon running? What is your window manager and java version?

Comment: please also check http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-80901 and http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860 - do these issue look similar?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After asking PhpStorm Support, I was suggested to use other type of JDK. He said because of a known bug for OpenJDK that should be fixed in the next minor IDEA release

Here is the link related
http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-79312

Then I tried to change using IBM JDK, but the problem still occured, and even make phpstorm quite slow.
Step by step how to (**note this dont solve my problem**, just FYI) : http://www.wikihow.com/Install-IBM-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux

From my point of view, PHPStorm has some problem with OpenJDK with different behavior. Mine is as I stated in my question. 
In addition, this problem happen not only after Find Occurence or using keyboard shortcut, but happen when I did nothing, it just happen pretty often.

Next I tried with oracle JDK, suggested with above link.
Step by step how to :
http://www.wikihow.com/Install-Oracle-Java-on-Ubuntu-Linux

Then the problem didn't occur again, after I have tested using a day without problem, so I write this answer.

Good Luck

Comment: I am having the same issue for a while now. The last article you linked to is the same article I used to setup JDK, but the issue still occurs for me. Did you install JDK or JRE? 32bit or 64bit?

Comment: I'm also still encountering this with the oracle java installation

Comment: from the jetbrains issue tracker: a workaround without having to restart phpstorm: `sudo ibus restart`

Comment: when i do sudo ibus restart, phpstorm crashes

Comment: Just a note, `ibus restart` also works for me, but also at the same time it switches keyboard layout to English (I am using Slovenian) so I have to play around with switching keyboard layouts so I can set it back to Slovenian. So it is quite tedious doing this every now and then so it's not really a solution.

Answer (score 23):

Try this

```
sudo ibus restart
```

Answer from here...https://askubuntu.com/questions/416504/phpstorm-losing-keyboard-input#answer-420131

This may switch your keyboard input by the way so reselect your keyboard input in the Ubuntu toolbar (I set mine to En1)

Not sure what causes this though, I'm using Guake and Compiz and have seen these tools behave a bit odd sometimes

Comment: There's no need to use "sudo" for this.

Comment: In case you have set up a different keyboard language you need to specify also the language: sudo ibus restart && setxkbmap de -> where de = german.

Comment: I'm not sure what this should do, but it completely breaks any input and now I can't even use my mouse (I'm using lxde if that matters)

Answer (score 15):

```
IBUS_ENABLE_SYNC_MODE=1 ibus-daemon --replace &
```

worked for me. You don't have to run `ibus restart` every so often.

Comment: Can you explain, please. Where are this code should be placed?

Comment: You can just paste it to the terminal, or append it to your `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: I added it in the file. I hope it works because this seems to be like a heisenbug

Comment: this one works for me on MacOS (Sierra), too - thanks!

Answer (score 6):

A compilation of some other fixes

1. add next line to /{path_where_phpstorm_is_installed}/bin/idea.properties and restart.

   actionSystem.suspendFocusTransferIfApplicationInactive=false
2. another option is to use Jdk 6 as it has low probability to happend
3. find next line at the end of bin/phpstorm.sh

   ```
   Run the IDE
   ```

   add next this lines

   ```
   XMODIFIERS=""
   export XMODIFIERS
   ```

The ibus restart solution was a temporarly solution to me as every 5  minutes (Ubuntu 15.05 with phpStorm 9) the problem ocurred again (It happens when you switch between windows Ctrl + tab).

[Ref1](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-79312), [Ref2](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-78860)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when switching tabs with alt+TAB. Very often it'd make the keyboard unresponsive and the only thing that helped was to restart PHPStorm. I've tried a different JDK and it didn't help neither.
My laptop is T430 running Ubuntu 13.10. I was running of the default graphic Nouveau driver. Then I switched to proprietary nvidia driver and it's been a few days and the issue hasn't occurred anymore (before it'd happen like 10-15x a day).
The only other thing I was doing was making suspend and hibernate work (with TuxOnIce)...not sure if it's related. So I'm suspecting the graphic driver change helped.

Michal

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I also have this issue. I've installed Oracle Java.
I had this situation when i open popup(for example settings) and next change window alt+tab. When I return to phpstorm then i can't typing. So now I try not to invoke this situation. I also noticed five minut ago :) that there is no necessity to restart phpstorm after this issue just enough to again change window alt+tab and now i can type again.

Update after @Taryn East comment:

Hi, sory but my answer was solution not "me too" case.

Then in simple words the solution is:

Try use alt+tab twice(change window and back again).
After this the problem should disappear.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow! it's a bit difficult to see whether this is a solution to the problem or a "me too"... if it's a solution - can you be more clear about how the original Poster can solve their problem using your solution? If it's not... then it's probably not really a good fit for an "answer". Now I recognise you're new and don't have enough rep to post comments yet - but "me too" comments are generally put only into the comments section (immediately below the original question).

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 ways to fix this: one is to set your DE to start the ibus daemon as you log in or edit your /bin/phpstorm.sh and add at beginning "export XMODIFIERS=" :

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
# PHPStorm startup script.
# ---------------------------------------------------------------------
#
export XMODIFIERS=""
```

Serves for any JetBrains app by editing the corresponding .sh

Answer (score 0):

just try :

[image: alt enter php storm intellij problem not working]

LEFT <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

<kbd>LEFT Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

> Looks like some languages override Right Alt behavior, at least in
>   case of Lithuanian Left Alt is working fine with Lithuanian enabled,
>   Right does not, when switch to English, everything is fine again. Was
>   pulling hair to figure out why out of nowhere it stops working, thanks